# File based changes

Tags: git, devops

I was learning Git from the link https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-What-is-Git%3F and I'm stuck in a part which states below things.

> The major difference between Git and any other VCS (Subversion and friends included) is the way Git thinks about its data. Conceptually, most other systems store information as a list of file-based changes. These other systems (CVS, Subversion, Perforce, and so on) think of the information they store as a set of files and the changes made to each file over time (this is commonly described as delta-based version control).

What does it mean by file-based changes?

I couldn't understand the meaning of the word.

Comment: Keep reading; it's explained in subsequent lines and the graphics. It's kind of a pity they include this in a "getting started" section; **you do not need to know any of this to use Git**.

Comment: They store the differences between the files between the revisions/commits..... so, say, SVN... to the best of my knowledge, it keeps the files as they are in `HEAD` (different from git `HEAD`, just in case) and then the differences between each revision going back.... so between `HEAD` and `HEAD~1` (or whatever way they write it), then `HEAD~1` and `HEAD~2`. In git it does not happen. git keeps the files as they are in each commit _without_ storing differences between the commits themselves.

Answer (score 2):

SVN and other older version control systems save "deltas" in commits, meaning that a commit contains the difference between the state of the files in the previous commit and the current commit.  Git, in contrast, saves a mini "snapshot" of the entire filesystem of your repo for each commit.  That means if you changed three files, those three files are stored in their entirety in the commit; for any files that didn't change Git simply stores a link to wherever the last point in git history that it was changed.  The outcome is that at any given commit you can easily put together the complete filesystem of your repo.  This gives git some operational benefits over other, older version control systems (VCSs).

However, as some comments stated, this is really probably unnecessary information for a beginner.  As someone getting started out with Git, you will probably get more effective education from actual practice and usage than you will reading about the underlying technology.  In fact, I suspect many people are able to use Git quite effectively without understanding how it works under the hood, the same way many people are able to drive without knowing anything about internal combustion engines.  Furthermore, this documentation was clearly written back when most people coming to Git were migrating from other VCSs they had been using for years; these days, Git will be the first and only VCS many people will learn, so opening the tutorial by contrasting it with other VCSs is probably unnecessary.

Ultimately, I'd say don't get too hung up understanding the inner-workings of Git right up front; try to move quickly into more hands-on exercises that will give you practical experience, and I suspect you will have an easier time from there.